# Elastic Search query without wildcard asterisk

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question related to ElasticSearch.
I have a document titled= "MS-PS_3.2"
When I search just for "MS" it returns the document based on query

```js
:query=>"*MS\\-PS_3.2*"
```

When I type in the full document title it doesn't return result. The query looks like following:

```js
:query=>"*MS\\-PS_3.2*"
```

However, when I remove the wildcard it returns the document

```js
:query=>"MS\\-PS_3.2"
```

My full query looks like following:

```js
 {:query=>{:bool=>{:must=>[{:query_string=>{:query=>"*MS\\-PS_3.2*"}}, {:terms=>{:bank_id=>[4]}}]}}, :size=>10000}
```

Is there something that I need to change in my query?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with `:query=>\*MS\\-PS_3.28\*` when you use query as part of request param.
When I use request body search, it seems to be working for me, however do you want to try with `"query" : "\\*MS\\-PS_3.2\\*"` ?

Comment: why would i want to escape the wildcard char?

Comment: Same reason as you are adding "\\" before "-"

Comment: it worked but it didnt make sense to me why i need to escape the wildcard char *. if the string contained * then  i can see escaping

Comment: I guess the reason is since your text has a reserved character("-") in it. More details are available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters).